# Dll на .NET Core для UWP/WPF/ASP.NET Core приложений

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, uwp, .net-core

На данный момент пишу приложение, которое бы работало на самых разнообразных платформах. По задумке, все типы приложений будут использовать общую модель и контроллер (ViewModel). Модель и контроллер были написаны в виде библиотек .dll на .NET Core 2.1, но загвоздка в том что не удаётся указать ссылку на библиотеку из WPF и UWP проектов.

На сколько мне известно, UWP приложения базируются на .NET Core платформе, однако при попытке указать ссылку возникает сообщение вида "Unable to add reference to project %ProjectName%". Для WPF нашёл решение в интернете базирующееся на компиляции либы в NuGet пакет, а для UWP проектов как я понимаю это решение не подходит.

Собственно вопрос, как можно выбраться из этой неприятной ситуации и использовать библиотеки из разных проектов? Модель и контроллер пишутся платформо-независимыми. Может быть существует более верный путь?

WPF приложение базируется на .NET Framework 4.7.1, а UWP приложение имеет версию UWP 6.1.5 (минимальная версия Fall Creators Update)

Comment: Я бы глядел в сторону .NET Standard - у меня как раз есть приложения на WPF и asp.net core 2, которые используют общую либy на .NET Standard

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо. А можно ли мигрировать уже созданный код библиотеки в библиотеку типа .NET Standart, или же можно только переносить уже созданный код руками?

Comment: Это, наверное, зависит от того, что вы использовали в своей библиотеке. Для меня переход на .NET Standard состоял просто в переключении Target Framework в свойствах проекта. Но я в своей либе ничего кроме сокетов и регулярок, не использовал.

Comment: Ну, и как пример, вот я делал [пулл реквест](https://github.com/marceldev89/BattleNET/pull/45) для конверта другой либы в .NET Standard 2

Comment: да, и ещё, в .NET Standard надо [вручную устанавливать кодировки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870084/net-core-doesnt-know-about-windows-1252-how-to-fix/37870346#37870346), из коробки из там нету

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, действительно всё получилось. Теперь на модель и контроллер могут ссылаться и WPF и UWP приложения. Для ретаргета с .NET Core на .NET Standard достаточно было поменять .csproj файл проекта, заменив `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>` на `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`

Comment: Я бы не советовал лазать в файлы проекта руками, просто в Solution Explorer нажимаете правой кнопкой на проекте - свойства - там есть поле Target Framework в виде выкидушки - выбираете там .NET Standart. Например, у меня после такого [не только](https://github.com/marceldev89/BattleNET/pull/45/files#diff-6fbd752c411d6973bee461d4d9556494) Target Framework поменялся

Comment: @tym32167 увы, в проекте .NET Core можно было выбирать только версии самого .NET Core'а, без возможности переключаться на другие платформы. Поэтому пришлось руками править

Comment: а, ок. Главное, что все получилось :)

Comment: @tym32167 Вы отстали от жизни. Лазать в файл проекта — теперь официально поддерживаемая фича новой проектной системы (.NET Core и Standard используют её, .NET Full тоже может, но по умолчанию ещё не использует). Файл можно редактировать без выгрузки проекта, многие изменения подхватываются на лету.

Comment: @Athari ничего я не отстал :) Лазать в файл проекта можно было всегда, ведь блокнот всегда под рукой. Я просто к тому, что зачем туда лазать, если можно не лазать (так было в моем случае, в случае автора, очевидно, другого выбора не было).

Comment: @tym32167 В новой проектной системе файл проекта — это не нагромождение сериализованных элементов в произвольном порядке, а чистый и аккуратный файл с кодом. Соответственно, при формальном сохранении формата .proj меняются методы его редактирования. Например, аналогично .designer.cs в WinForms — это формат сериализации, а .xaml — код. Первое редактируется кнопочками, второе — ручками (хотя и то и другое, можно изменять и тем, и другим способом). К слову, далеко не все возможности .proj доступны через GUI, включая мультитаргет и сборку в одну директорию.

Comment: @Athari спасибо, что пытаетесь мне пояснить эти вещи, но вы попусту тратите время, так как я это уже знаю и всё это уже проходил, и переход на project.json, и возврат к XML формату, и облегченный формат XML. Единственное, чего я не знал, это что нельзя у .net core приложения в свойствах проекта сменить target framework на .net standard - о чем мне поведал автор вопроса.

Comment: @tym32167 Тогда я не понимаю, почему вы принимаете в штыки редактирование файла проекта.

Comment: @Athari никаких штыков, я просто предпочитаю не лазать в файл проекта.  В повседневной работе у меня старая студия и обычный WPF (тыкать палкой в новинки от MS - это больше хобби, чем работа), потому привычки лазать руками в файлы проекта у меня нет и от этого действия у меня до сих пор ощущение, что то то происходит не так, как должно быть.